# Why does the Math.random() keep updating onClick?

Tags: javascript, html

So upon learning a few JavaScript functions, I wanted to make a guessing game, this is my code: (EDITED)

```
<body>
  <script>
    var a;
    function rand(){
        var a = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1);
    }

    function random() {
      guess = document.getElementById('gess').value;
      if(guess < a) {
        document.getElementById('gus').innerHTML = 'To small!';

      }
      else if(guess > a) {
        document.getElementById('gus').innerHTML = 'To big!';
      }
      else if(guess == a) {
        document.getElementById('gus').innerHTML = 'Correct! The secret number is ' + a;

      } 

    }


  </script>
  <h1> Guess the secret number! </h1>
  <input type='text' id='gess'>
  <input type='button' onClick='random()' value='Guess!'>
  <input type='button' value='Reset Number' onClick='rand()'> 
  <br>
  <p id='gus'> </p>
</body>
```

What do I do, for the random number (a) to stop refreshing every time I click 'Guess', thank you in advance!

Comment: Why wouldn't it, it's what it's supposed to do, spit out a random number everytime you call it?

Comment: because your telling it to.

Comment: I get it now, sorry :S I'm pretty new to js, I had to put it outside the function, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do this:

```
var a = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1);
function random() {...}
```

That will store the random number before the random function is called. Otherwise, `a` will be reset every time.

Comment: Thank you! I'l keep that in mind, so every time I click the button, it re-runs through the function, while updating the random number, thank you!

Comment: Yes. If you want to reset the random number, you should do it in another function.

Comment: I made a function rand() and I put the variable inside of it, then I made a button with the onClick to rand(), and now the text won't appear when I enter a number, why is that?

Comment: Because if you declare the variable within a function, it is only visible within that function. What you should do is `var a;` before the function, then `a = ...` within the function.

Comment: var a;
    function random() {
      var a = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1);

Comment: The problem is that you did `var a =...;` This makes a new variable `a` within the function that is only visible within the function.

Comment: So where do I put the `var a =...;`

Comment: Do this. `var a;function rand(){
        a = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1);
    }`

Comment: No you have `var a; function rand() {VAR a = ...;}`

Comment: I have to click reset number every time i start, makes sense now, sorry for the trouble, thank you! :)

Comment: You can have the page run the function once automatically by calling `rand()` at the end of the script.